# Are there any GURPS blogs?

Tags: gurps

I have seen tons of blogs for other games (D&D, etc), but never a blog that deals solely, mostly, or even regularly with GURPS.  Are there any (good) ones out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This site [T Bones Games Diner](http://www.gamesdiner.com/) has a lot of GURPS related articles but as I don't play GURPS I can't comment on it's quality.  :)

Comment: The quality is excellent.

Comment: Agreed - TBone has a lot of good suggestions here and is a great place to start getting your rules tinkering fix.

Answer (score 12):

- http://siskoid.blogspot.com/
  __I found this blog, which seems generally system-agnostic, but deals with GURPS sometimes.
- http://criticalfailuregame.wordpress.com/
  __This is a GURPS podcast, apparently. Haven't had time to listen to it.
- http://dr-kromm.livejournal.com/
  __Personal and professional blog of Sean "Dr. Kromm" Punch, the line editor for GURPS.
- http://www.superawesomeblog.com/category/rpg/
  __This blog as a whole is mostly non-GURPS, but this link is to ~two pages of GURPS posts.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of very good quality GURPS blogs I found recently:

- [Gaming Ballistic](http://gamingballistic.blogspot.ca/)
- [Dungeon Fantastic](http://dungeonfantastic.blogspot.ca/)
- [Renovating the Temple](http://d20to3d6.blogspot.ca/)

Answer (score 3):

[The Cheese Shop](http://thecheeseshop.org) is another small blog devoted to GURPS.

Answer (score 2):

Following the links to Gaming Ballistic and Dungeon Fantastic will get you to a host of other GURPS blogs as well:

From GB:

[No School Grognard](http://noschoolgrognard.blogspot.com/)

[One Yard Hex](http://oneyardhex.blogspot.com/)

[Ravens n Pennies](http://ravensnpennies.blogspot.com/) - this one is by Christopher Rice, one of the most prolific authors in Pyramid Magazine.

[Game in the Brain](http://gameinthebrain.blogspot.com/)

[Insidious GURPS Planning](http://insidiousgurpsplanning.blogspot.com/)

[RPG Snob](http://rpgsnob.blogspot.com/)

[Testujin No Llama](http://tetsujinnollama.blogspot.com/) Matt Riggsby's blog. Good stuff.

From DF:

[Sorcerer's Labyrinth](http://www.sorcererslabyrinth.com/)

[German Geek](http://german-geek.blogspot.com/)

[Don't Forget Your Boots](http://mshrm.wordpress.com/)